# Determining SPL experimentally with calibration data, output Vrms, and gain

Tags: voltage, amplifier, microphone

Hi all I have a microphone calibrated at a SPL of 94 dB which produces an output Vrms of 1.7. I have an amplifier gain of 40 dB and need to convert measured Vrms values into SPL (dB).

Should I solve this by using GdB = 20log(Vrms_out / Vrms_in) to calculate the Vrms_in and then using Vrms in with the calibration information to determine the equivalent SPL? SPL_measured = (SPL_calibrated * Vrms_in)/ Vrms_calibrated

Or should I use the calibration data to convert output Vrms into SPL then subtract the gain to get the real SPL?

I am a mechanical engineer in a grad level acoustics class. The only info I ever got on signals was from a freshman instrumentation class and cant seem to remember what to do here.

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Are you sure about the values? 40dB is 100. An amplifier would need to output 170V if input is 1.7V and both voltages seem excessively high.

Comment: Hi there, this is from a homework assignment so im assuming its more theoretical than realistic. This is what it says in the assignment: Experimental Measurements

A microphone was calibrated at Lp = 94 dB producing an output of 1.7 Vrms.
The microphone amplifier gain is 40 dB.  
The acoustic measurements were made at r = 1.4 m.  
Microphone->Amplifier->Voltmeter

Comment: The purpose of this assignment is to make polar plots of a speakers directivity. I have to compare the theoretical vs measured using Lp vs theta

Comment: You can calculate the result in either order and the result will be the same, just try it. But there is no mention at what distance the 94dB is 1.7Vrms, do you have to assume it is 1m and take the speaker distance not being 1m but 1.4m into account?

Comment: I think the assumption is that all measurements and the calibration were done at 1.4m. I will give a try calculating both ways I described. Thank you for the confirmation on the equations.

Comment: I did not confirm your equations. Now that I looked at them, at least the latter is wrong. With 0Vrms you would get 0 dB, that can't be right. So if you have output Vrms, work out the input Vrms and it's relation to reference in dB. You know that 1.7Vrms is 0dB compared to reference 1.7Vrms and that's 94dB SPL.

Comment: My first output is 0.15 Vrms. If I solve for Vrms_in: (40 = 20log(0.15/Vrms_in), then for  SPL = (94*Vrms_in)/1.7, this would not be correct?

Comment: No. You can't handle decibels as linear quatities. If you want to handle linear quantities, convert the reference of 94 dB SPL to pressure first. Or just handle decibels like decibels are supposed to be handled.

Answer (score 1):

Every module has a transfer function which has the sensitivity in dB that may vary with frequency, then correlate SPL of 94 dB or  dBA (?) to voltage 1.7 = 4.6 dBV with 1V = 0dBV and 2V=6 dBV

Then measure PA input and output dBV with the gain being the difference (using 20 log V)

You have to make conversion factors from Vout dBV to SPL.  Your speakers also have a transfer function of dBV to SPL that varies with f.

Then decide how you can use this info and as the results with speaker sensitivity and source spectrum which affects the results.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with acoustics, it is customary to use dB as it makes the arithmetic easy. We'll also assume that you are in the far-field. If in the near-field, then you will get constructive-destructive interference patterns (Fresnel zone) which will mess up your measurements. Echos from surfaces (walls, floor, ceiling) will also mess up your results which is why pulse or impulse measurements are used when characterizing speakers.

Given: SPL at mic is 94 dB. We'll assume this is referenced to 20 µPa since you are talking about acoustics in air.

We'll assume the output of the amplifier is 1.7 V (not clear if the 1.7 V is the output voltage of the mic or amp) with a SPL of 94 dB which is equivalent to 4.6 dBV = 20log(1.7). Treat the mic+amplifier as a single entity to make life easier.

The microphone+amplifier sensitivity is:
$$ H = Vout_{dBV} - SPL = 4.6 - 94 = -89.4 dB \; re \; 1V/20 \mu Pa$$
Beware, \$H\$ most likely varies with frequency. Reference microphones are given with sensitivity versus frequency data.

The speaker source level, SL, is given by: 
$$ SL = Vout_{dBV} - H + TL $$
Where:
\$ \;\;H = \$ sensitivity of the microphone+amplifier entity
\$ \;\;Vout_{dbV} = \$ amplifier output voltage in dBV
\$ \;\;TL = \$ transmission loss \$ = 20log(R) \$. This assumes  spherical spreading is your only loss.
\$ \;\;R = \$ range between speaker and microphone in metres